# Android get click information object on screen

Tags: android

I have 10 `TextView` on screen . Now i want get id,string of `Textview` which i click.
I don't want `setOnClickListener` for every `textview` .
Sorry for bad English.

[image]

Comment: Explain your requirement

Comment: There are many approaches to this. Post some code that you have tried or at least what you have so far.

Comment: i updated image . help me thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `TextView` are defined in XML then set `clickable:"true"` and then `onClick:"onTextViewClick"` to all of your TextViews.

Then in your activity create a method like this:

```
void onTextViewClick(View view){
    int clickedId = view.getId();
}
```

Comment: thank ,it work  , i have one more question .have any other short way to do this with code if i have 100-200 textview . i dont want write it in XML file one by one .

Comment: If you are creating the `TextView`s dynamically in code then implement `OnClickListener` in your `Activity` and override `onClick(View view)` method. Then call `setOnClickListener(this)` for every `TextView`.